Use figure returned from a function as a subplot in a new figure
I have a class where some methods generate and returns the figure it creates as an object with its axes.
In a new method, I want to use the figures generated by the other functions as a subplot.
How could one achieve that?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np

class SomethingCool():
    def plot1(self):
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        x2 = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
        y = np.linspace(50,80,100)

        fig = plt.figure(figsize(8,8))
        gs = GridSpec(1,1,figure=fig)

        axa = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
        axa.plot(x, y)
        axb = axa.twiny(x)
        axb.plot(x2,y)
        fig.set_tight_layout(True)
        fig.show()

        return fig, (axa, axb)

    def plot2(self):
        x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
        x2 = np.linspace(0, 200, 100)
        y = np.linspace(0,100,100)

        fig = plt.figure(figsize(8,8))
        gs = GridSpec(1,1,figure=fig)

        axa = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
        axa.plot(x, y)
        axb = axa.twiny(x)
        axb.plot(x2,y)
        fig.set_tight_layout(True)
        fig.show()

        return fig, (axa, axb)

    def new_plot(self):
        fig1, (axesa, axesb) = self.plot1()
        fig2, (axes2a, axes2b) = self.plot2()

        x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,100)
        y = np.sin(x)

        fig = plt.figure() 
        gs = GridSpec(1,2,figure=fig)

        axa = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:])
        axa.plot(x,y)

        # now I want plot1 to be in gs[1,0] and plot2 in gs[1,1]



Why can't you just define the Gridspec object and relative axes in the init and then use the methods to plot on the already existing axes?

Because in the class I have various methods creating plot of different sizes. So one is a 1x1 and another may be a 3x2.

OK, maybe then define them as an instance variable: self.gs =gs? So you can access them everywhere?
